# How to run command-line command on non-contiguous lines, specifying individual line numbers?

Tags: vim

For example, say I want to replace `foo` with `bar` on lines 1,3,11, and 15.  How could I do that?

```
:1,15s/foo/bar
```

will replace `foo` with `bar` on lines 1-15.  But I want to specify multiple individual lines (1,3,11,15), not a range (1-15).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way: Execute the `:substitute` for the first line, then repeat the same substitution with `:&&` on the following lines.

```
:execute '1s/foo/bar' | 5&& | 11&& | 15&&
```

Another way: Use the `:global` command with a pattern that matches only in the lines.

```
:g/\%1l\|\%5l\|\%11l\|\%15l/s/foo/bar
```

Third way: Use a loop:

```
:for l in [1,5,11,15] | execute l.'s/foo/bar' | endfor
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks @Ingo_Karkat!  I really like the 3 different options.

Answer (score 1):

How do you come up with the line numbers? If this is a manual process of visual inspection, you could make use of the [multiselect plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=953). It allows you to select multiple, non-contiguous ranges, and then you can apply a command on them:

```
:MSExecCmd s/foo/bar
```